# Why is are there duplicates of same data while reading documents from sub-collection in FIrestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-futurebuilder

I am trying to get the document IDs or the data inside the those documents of sub-collection which are present within a existing document which belongs to a Bigger collection.

The structure is as follows.

> Collection>Document>Sub-Collection>Document :
> Users>Shaiyan>Statuses>05 Feb 2022 - 03 Mar 2022 I have photos to show
> this structure.

My problem is, when I read every data inside each document inside the sub-collection I get a proper list. But when I specify a document Id inside which I want to read the data, I get duplicate values in the list as shown below.

[Firestore structure - 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YFNd.png)

[Firestore structure - 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOeCu.png)

This is the code I am using to get the all the data from firestore.

```
Future getDocIDs() async {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Users')
      //.orderBy('rank', descending: false)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
              //print(document.reference);
              //documentIDs.add(document.reference.id);
              db
                  .collection('Users')
                  .doc(document.reference.id)
                  .collection("Statuses")
                  .get()
                  .then((value) {
                value.docs.forEach((element) {
                  //print(element.data());
                  documentIDs.add(element.data().toString());
                });
              });
            })
          });
  print(documentIDs);
  print(documentIDs.length);
  setState(() {});
}
```

[Output on getting all the the documents data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1P5J.png)

This is the code I am using to get the particular data, namely of person named **"Shaiyan"** from firestore.

```
Future getDocIDs() async {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Users')
      //.orderBy('rank', descending: false)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
              //print(document.reference);
              //documentIDs.add(document.reference.id);
              db
                  .collection('Users')
                  .doc('Shaiyan')
                  .collection("Statuses")
                  .get()
                  .then((value) {
                value.docs.forEach((element) {
                  //print(element.data());
                  documentIDs.add(element.data().toString());
                });
              });
            })
          });
  print(documentIDs);
  print(documentIDs.length);
  setState(() {});
}
```

[Output on setting the document Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hf6vU.png)

This is the place I call this function

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: **getDocIDs**,
    child: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [
            Colors.deepPurple.shade400,
            Colors.deepPurple.shade700,
          ],
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
        ),
        //color: Colors.deepPurple,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      ),
      child: const Center(
        child: Text(
          'Print subcollection',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

I will attach screen shots of out puts on the issue as well

Comment: You're mixing async/await with then/catch.  That's a bad idea.  Just use one or the other, and generally prefer async/await.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having access to your full data set it is difficult to tell for sure, but I think you can solve it by separating the two different loops you are running. In the current code you shared, you are getting all users:

```
Future getDocIDs() async {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Users')
      //.orderBy('rank', descending: false)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
```

Then inside each user, you are getting their status:

```
            snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
              //print(document.reference);
              //documentIDs.add(document.reference.id);
              db
                  .collection('Users')
                  .doc(document.reference.id)
                  .collection("Statuses")
                  .get()
                  .then((value) {
                value.docs.forEach((element) {
                  //print(element.data());
                  documentIDs.add(element.data().toString());
                });
              });
            })
```

In your second example, you are still getting all users, but then inside each user you are getting only the docs for user Shaiyan. That means you are potentially getting Shaiyan's docs multiple times resulting in duplicates.

Instead try separating these into different functions. First get all users or a list of user IDs. Then loop through the list of user IDs and get the subcollection documents for each user ID. This would give you greater control and the opportunity to verify that the subcollection request for an individual user is only being called one time.

In other words, you just need to call this part of the code one time:

```
              db
                  .collection('Users')
                  .doc('Shaiyan')
                  .collection("Statuses")
                  .get()
                  .then((value) {
                value.docs.forEach((element) {
                  //print(element.data());
                  documentIDs.add(element.data().toString());
                });
              });
```

But because it is inside a forEach loop, you are actually calling it 17 times, and thus getting a list with the same result 17 times.

Comment: Yeah I was getting duplicate of the same person. Thanks I got the gist of the problem